# Reverse proxy server configuration with 2 different servers in iis

Tags: iis, networking, server

I want to create reverse proxy server for two different server (A) public server which is in one VPN and server (B) which is in another VPN I have tried reverse proxy from this blog given below its not working please help me out

[https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222#:~:text=Setup%20a%20Reverse%20Proxy%20rule%20using%20the%20Wizard.&text=Select%20the%20URL%20Rewrite%20Icon,Inbound%20and%20Outbound%20Rules'%20category](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222#:%7E:text=Setup%20a%20Reverse%20Proxy%20rule%20using%20the%20Wizard.&text=Select%20the%20URL%20Rewrite%20Icon,Inbound%20and%20Outbound%20Rules%27%20category).

Comment: Have you encountered any errors? Are there any things you don't understand? Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: after configuring the reverse proxy i am getting 500 internal server error

Comment: Please post the details of the error instead of just telling me a status code. You can use F12 to view the error information in the console or check the  error information in the Event Viewer.